# Validation only works for one View in a MultiView at a time

Tags: asp.net, validation, dynamic, multiview

I am having MultiView with 2 Views in my web form. view1 having validation group group1, view2 having validation group group2. validations are created from C# code-behind.

1. If view1 loading first then group1 validation working fine, but view2 validation did not work.
2. If view2 loading first then group2 validation works fine, but view1 validation did not work.

Here is example code:

```
         if (dtr["Block_Type"].ToString() == "DataBlock")
                {
                    RequiredFieldValidator rq = new RequiredFieldValidator();
                    rq.ID = "rq" + strTextBox;
                    rq.InitialValue = "";
                    rq.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
                    rq.ErrorMessage = Convert.ToString(dtr["CONTROL_TEXT"]);
                    rq.Text = Convert.ToString(dtr["CONTROL_TEXT"]);
                    rq.ControlToValidate = strTextBox;
                    rq.ValidationGroup = "dbgrpMandate";
                    controlID.Controls.Add(rq);
                }
                else
                {
                    CustomValidator cv = new CustomValidator();
                    cv.ID = "cv" + strTextBox;
                    cv.ValidationGroup = "qbgrpMandate";
                    cv.ClientValidationFunction = "QBValidation";
                    cv.ControlToValidate = strTextBox;
                    cv.ValidateEmptyText = true;
                    cv.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
                    cv.ErrorMessage = Convert.ToString(dtr["CONTROL_TEXT"]);
                    cv.Text = Convert.ToString(dtr["CONTROL_TEXT"]);
                    controlID.Controls.Add(cv);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use global validation which can be validate all part of controller to validate all the view forms: [Validate Global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19677490/mvc-code-or-model-first/19678461#19678461)